# Django tooltip translation not working with white spaces

Tags: html, django, django-templates, internationalization, django-i18n

I am translating an html tooltip using i18n which does not show when it is between translation tags {% translate ... %} unless spaces are removed.

Code without translate tag:

```
<th scope="col">{% trans '% Name' %} <span class="tt" data-bs-placement="bottom" title= 'Some normal text (NT) with spaces.'><i class="bi bi-question-circle-fill hover-only" style="font-size: 1.2rem;"></i></span></th>
```

[image: No translate tag]

The code with translation tag shows only the first word before the white space.

```
<th scope="col">{% trans '% Name' %} <span class="tt" data-bs-placement="bottom" title= {% translate 'Some normal text (NT) with spaces.' %}><i class="bi bi-question-circle-fill hover-only" style="font-size: 1.2rem;"></i></span></th>
```

[image: Translation tag with white space]

When the white spaces are removed with _, the whole text shows even if between the {% translate .. %} tag.

```
<th scope="col">{% trans '% Name' %} <span class="tt" data-bs-placement="bottom" title= {% translate 'Some_normal_text_(NT)_with_spaces.' %}><i class="bi bi-question-circle-fill hover-only" style="font-size: 1.2rem;"></i></span></th>
```

[image: Whole text with no white space]

Anyone knows how to show the whole text with white spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes in the translate tag demarcate the string, but aren't part of it.  So when it's translated, you have no attribute quotes for title.

```
title= {% translate 'Some normal text (NT) with spaces.' %}
```

Should be

```
title= "{% translate 'Some normal text (NT) with spaces.' %}"
```

Or

```
title= {% translate '"Some normal text (NT) with spaces."' %}
```

Otherwise the browser is assuming the first word is the string, because there are no quotes to encompass the rest of the string.